# readobject method throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, client, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to pick up Java and wanted to test around with Java's client/server to make the client send a simple object of a self defined class(Message) over to the server. The problem was that I kept getting a ClassNotFoundException on the server side.

I think the rest of the codes seem to be alright because other objects such as String can go through without problems.

I had two different netbeans projects in different locations for client and server each.

Each of them have their own copy of Message class under their respective packages.
Message class implements Serializable.

On the client side, I attempt to send a Message object through.

On the server side, upon calling the readObject method, it seems to be finding Message class from the client's package instead of it's own. printStackTrace showed: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.Message" on the server side

I have not even tried to cast or store the object received yet. Is there something I left out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The package name and classname must be **exactly** the same at the both sides. I.e. write once, compile once and then give the both sides the *same* copy. Don't have separate `server.Message` and `client.Message` classes, but a single `shared.Message` class or something like that.

If you can guarantee the same package/class name, but not always whenever it's *exactly* the same copy, then you need to add a `serialVersionUID` field with the same value to the class(es) in question.

```
package shared;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: And please don't make the serialUID exactly 1L, because this could interfere with other stupid developer having the same idea.

Comment: It works now! Thank you~!! At last I finally understand what's going on

Comment: @BalusC- This SO cool. I was breaking my head over it for days.

Comment: Works like churm, 7 years down the line - "Don't have separate server.Message and  client.Message classes, but a single shared.Message class or something like that.

If you can guarantee the same package/class name, but not always whenever it's exactly the same copy,"

Answer (score 4):

The reason is, that the readObject() in ObjectInputStream is practically implemented as:

```
 String s = readClassName();
 Class c = Class.forName(s); // Here your code breaks
 Object o = c.newInstance();
 ...populate o...
```

Comment: question is why?