# readobject method throws ClassNotFoundException with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, serialization, classnotfoundexception

I am using MATLAB and call some Java inside. Basically after I created an Java Object, I wanted to convert it into a Byte Array which I can store as MATLAB array in my DB. After loading the array I want to transform it back to Java to be used as Java Object again. Here is the code, which is simpler in MATLAB:

The class of myJavaObject is: weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg

```
baos = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

oos = java.io.ObjectOutputStream(baos);

oos.writeObject(myJavaObject);
```

% Now I can store it into the DB and load it from there. It should be rebuild to Java:

```
myJavaObject = baos.toByteArray;

bais = java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(myJavaObject);

ois = java.io.ObjectInputStream(bais);

ois.readObject;
```

All is fine until I I call ois.readObject. Now I get an ClassNotFoundException exception. I've read many discusssion about problems that the object must have the same class like here: [readobject method throws ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916107/readobject-method-throws-classnotfoundexception)

I am very happy about any ideas and help! Thanks!!!

Ben