# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Message using maven and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, voip

I coded a little socket client/server app using eclipse. Aiming to use maven capabilities for dependencies, I created a new maven project where I copy and paste exactly the same code as before.

However, every time i try to connect from the client app the following exception is triggered:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Message

Comment: Can you paste code where exception is throwed an also the full stack trace?

Comment: Can you paste code where exception is thrown and also the full stack trace?

Comment: What do you think the error message means?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps guys. The issue was related to the code itself. 

I found the solution in the url before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916107/readobject-method-throws-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
maven clean install
```

If you are in eclipse, try `alt + f5` in project to execute maven update.

Hope help you.